# MySQL count unique rows based on multiple factors

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find unique rows based on unique ip and then get the result sorted by users in single query.

I am trying this way

```
$query="SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT `userip`) AS `count`,
`userid` AS `userid`
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE (`date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) GROUP BY `userid`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
print_r($row);
```

This gives me result for last user as

```
Array ( [count] => xxx [userid] => last_user);
```

I need to get this result for every user in single query as

```
Array ( 
    Array ( [count] => xxx [userid] => first_user);
    .
    .
    Array ( [count] => xxx[userid] => last_user);
)
```

Please see if this can be done, and suggest a way to do it.
Thanks

**Edit**

Thanks for all the answers, The solution is working I was checking query on row instead of result.

Comment: try this `SELECT 
userid,count(*) as count
FROM tablename
WHERE (date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) GROUP BY userid,userip`

Comment: @FerozAkbar it didn't work giving same result

Comment: take userip also `SELECT userid,userip,count(*)`

Comment: @FerozAkbar didn't work returns only last user info

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by this way

```
$query = "SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS `count`,
`userid` AS `userid`
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE (`date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) GROUP BY `userid`";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use group by on both columns userip and userid columns. See if below query works for you.

```
SELECT COUNT( `userip`) AS `count`, `userid` AS `userid` FROM `tablename` WHERE (`date` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())) GROUP BY userid,userip;
```

Answer (score 0):

oh you have to fetch the results in loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u_ip), count(u_id) AS count FROM t1 GROUP BY u_ip;
```

then loop in php use `for loop` or `foreach`

```
for ($i=0;$i<$row;$i++)
{
   echo "<tr><td>".$result["u_id"][$i]."</td><td>".$result["count"][$i];
}
```

or use

```
foreach ($result as $res){}
```